# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Home without an ID):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `homes` table, `users`, and `payments`. I want something like this, when a user creates a payment, it should contain `user_id` and `home_id`. I have managed to get `user_id` working but `home_id` failing.

I could be having problems with this line of code:

```
home = Home.find(params[:home_id])
```

where I wanted to find home with an id that I used while creating payments

`PaymentsController`:

```
class Api::V1::PaymentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_payment, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    # GET /payments or /payments.json
    def index
     if user_signed_in?
        @payments = current_user.payments.order(created_at: :desc)
            render json: @payments
         else
            render json: {}, status: 401
        end
    end

    # GET /payments/1 or /payments/1.json
    def show
        if @payment
          render json: @payment
        else
          render json:@payment.errors  
      end
    end
   
    # GET /payments/new
    def new
      payment = current_user.payments.new
    #   home = Home.find(params[:home_id])  
    end
  
    # GET /payments/1/edit
    def edit
    end
  
    # POST /payments or /payments.json
    def create 
        home = Home.find(params[:home_id])
        if user_signed_in? 
            payment = home.payments.create(payment_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))
            if payment = current_user.payments.create(payment_params, home)
             render json: payment, status: :created 
             else 
                render json: payment.errors, status: 400
            end
        else 
            render json: {}, status: 401
        end
    end
    
    # PATCH/PUT /payments/1 or /payments/1.json
    def update
      if @payment.update(payment_params)
        render json: {notice: "Payment was successfully updated." }
      else
        render json: { error: 'Unable to update payment' }
      end
    end
  
    # DELETE /payments/1 or /payments/1.json
    def destroy
      @payment.destroy
        render json: {notice: 'Payment succefully removed'}
    end
  
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_payment
      @payment = Payment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def payment_params
      params.require(:payment).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :address, :money_paid, :date, :nin_number, :user_id, :home_id)
    end
end
```

Schema:

```
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# This file is the source Rails uses to define your schema when running `bin/rails
# db:schema:load`. When creating a new database, `bin/rails db:schema:load` tends to
# be faster and is potentially less error prone than running all of your
# migrations from scratch. Old migrations may fail to apply correctly if those
# migrations use external dependencies or application code.
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2022_12_15_071948) do

  create_table "homes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "image_url"
    t.decimal "price", precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.string "availability", default: "Available", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "payments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "phone_number"
    t.text "address"
    t.decimal "money_paid"
    t.string "nin_number"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "home_id"
    t.date "date"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["home_id"], name: "index_payments_on_home_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_payments_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "payments", "homes"
  add_foreign_key "payments", "users"
end
```

`home.rb`:

```
class Home < ApplicationRecord
    validates :title, :description, :image_url, :price,  :availability, presence: true
    validates :price, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01 }
   

    validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
        with:
        %r{\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg)\z}i,
        message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG, JPEG or PNG image.'
    }
    
    has_many :payments
end
```

`payment.rb`:

```
class Payment < ApplicationRecord
    validates :first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :address, :money_paid, :date, :nin_number, :user_id, presence: true
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :home
end
```

`user.rb`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
         has_many :payments
end
```

How  can I go about it? I want payments to include `user_id` and `home_id` which the user is paying for.

Here are my routes if it could be a routing error

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      get 'homes/index'
      post 'homes/create'
      get '/show/:id', to: 'homes#show'
      delete '/destroy/:id', to: 'homes#destroy'
      # resources :payments

      get '/payments/index'
      post '/payments/create'
    end
   
  end

  root 'homes#index' 
  
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

`am using react at the front end to send requests to the server and below is my payment.jsx where i pass in params`

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { Button, Form, Input, InputNumber, Select, DatePicker } from 'antd';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Payment = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const form = useRef();
    const onFinish = (values) => {
        // values.preventDefault();
        let token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
        const url = "/api/v1/payments/create";
        fetch(url, {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                'X-CSRF-Token': token
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(values),
        })
        .then((data) => {
            if (data.ok) {
                return data.json();
            }
            throw new Error("Network error.");
        })
        // Displaying results to console
        .then(data => console.log(data));
        navigate('/')
    };

    return (
        <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", marginTop: 20 }}>
            <Form ref={form} onFinish={onFinish} layout="vertical" initialValues={{ prefix: '256', }} scrollToFirstError labelCol={{ span: 15 }} wrapperCol={{ span: 24}}>
                <Form.Item
                    name="first_name"
                    label="First Name"
                    rules={[
                        {
                            required: true,
                            message: 'Please input your first name!',
                            whitespace: true,
                        },
                    ]}
                >
                    <Input placeholder='Input Your First Name' />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item
                    name="last_name"
                    label="Last Name"
                    rules={[
                        {
                            required: true,
                            message: 'Please input your last name!',
                            whitespace: true,
                        },
                    ]}
                >
                    <Input placeholder='Input Your Last Name' />
                </Form.Item>

                <Form.Item
                    name="phone_number"
                    label="Phone Number"
                    rules={[
                        {
                            required: true,
                            message: 'Please input your phone number!',
                        },
                    ]}
                >
                    <Input
                        style={{
                            width: '100%',
                        }}
                        placeholder='Input Your Phone number'
                    />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item
                    name="nin_number"
                    label="NIN Number"
                    rules={[
                        {
                            required: true,
                            message: 'Please input your National Identification number!',
                        },
                    ]}
                >
                    <Input
                        placeholder='Input Your National Identification Number'
                        style={{
                            width: '100%',
                        }}
                    />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item
                    name="money_paid"
                    label="Money Paid"
                    rules={[
                        {
                            required: true,
                            message: 'Please input amount paid!',
                        },
                    ]}
                >
                    <InputNumber
                        style={{
                            width: '100%',
                        }}
                        placeholder='Input Amount Paid'
                    />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item name="date" label="Date" rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please select date!', }]}>
                    < DatePicker
                        style={{
                            width: '100%',
                        }}
                    />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item
                    name="address"
                    label="address"
                    rules={[
                        {
                            required: true,
                            message: 'Please input For place of address',
                        },
                    ]}
                >
                    <Input.TextArea showCount maxLength={100} />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item >
                    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                        Make Payment
                    </Button>
                </Form.Item>
            </Form>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Payment;
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to the stack! THe error message suggests that `:home_id` is not set in the `params`. That means it's likely not send by the view. Can you please add how you send the `new` form (HTML, Javascript, ...) and maybe even a log from the action?

Comment: `am using react at the front end and below here is how i send my request to back end`const onFinish = (values) => {
        // values.preventDefault();
        let token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
        const url = "/api/v1/payments/create";
        fetch(url, {
            method: "post",headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                'X-CSRF-Token': token
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(values),
        })

Comment: @Cpt.Hook am using react at front end and rails at back end but combined together.

Comment: i have updated my question with payment.jsx where i pass in the params

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is your routes. To start with use the `resources :homes` macro and create the [idomatically correct routes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default):

```
Prefix     Verb     URI Pattern              Controller#Action
homes      GET      /homes(.:format)         homes#index
           POST     /homes(.:format)         homes#create
home       GET      /homes/:id(.:format)     homes#show
           PATCH    /homes/:id(.:format)     homes#update
           PUT      /homes/:id(.:format)     homes#update
           DELETE   /homes/:id(.:format)     homes#destroy
```

> Browsers request pages from Rails by making a request for a URL using a specific HTTP method, such as GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, and DELETE. Each method is a request to perform an operation on the resource. A resource route maps a number of related requests to actions in a single controller.

You don't need or want to add `/create` and `/delete` to the path and doing so won't reflect well on your compentency. Rails is strongly convention driven and things just work when you follow the conventions.

The `/new` and `/edit` actions are an exception to this rule but they are just used to render forms in classical applications. They are not commonly used in APIs.

To create relations between different relations in your routes you use [nested routes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
resources :homes do 
  resources :payments, shallow: true
end
```

This creates `POST /homes/:home_id/payments` route to create payments for a specific home and a `GET /homes/:home_id/payments` to show all the payments. Make sure you update your JS or form to submit to the correct path.

The controller is a real mess. Mostly of the mess is stemming from the fact that you haven't really understood how to use the authentication system or even defined a coherent set of rules.

I would just set it up now to only allow authenticated users and if you later want to let un-authenticated users create payments then put on your thinking cap and write tests and consider all the implications and edge cases first.

```
# Use explicit nesting to avoid unexpected constant lookup
# and autoloading bugs 
# https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition
class Api
  module V1
    class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_payment, only: %i[ show update destroy ]
      # before_action :authenticate_user! will raise an 
      # error if the user isn't signed in
      # if you want to allow unauthenticated users use:
      #  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:foo, :bar, :baz]
      before_action :authenticate_user!

      # GET homes/:home_id/payments 
      def index
        render json: home.payments.order(created_at: :desc)
      end

      # GET /payments/1 or /payments/1.json
      def show
        render json: @payment
      end
    
      # you do not need new or edit in an API.

      # POST /homes/:home_id/payments 
      def create 
        # Use `.new` instead of create which also saves the record 
        payment = home.payments.new(payment_params) do |p|
          p.user = current_user # if user_signed_in?
        end
        if payment.save
          render json: payment, status: :created 
        else
          render json: payment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
      end
      
      # @todo How do you plan on authorizing that the user can only edit 
      # payments they have created? And is letting users update the payment 
      # even a good idea?
      # PATCH/PUT /payments/1 or /payments/1.json
      def update
        if @payment.update(payment_params)
          # Avoid the "JSON messages" anti-pattern and make sure 
          # your API always returns meaningful HTTP status codes
          render json: { notice: "Payment was successfully updated." },
                 status: :ok
        else
          render json: { error: 'Unable to update payment' },
                 status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
      end

      # DELETE /payments/1 or /payments/1.json
      def destroy
        @payment.destroy
        render json: {notice: 'Payment succefully removed'}
      end

    private
      def home
        @home ||= Home.find(params[:home_id])
      end

      # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
      def set_payment
        @payment = Payment.find(params[:id])
      end

      # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
      def payment_params
        params.require(:payment)
              .permit(
                 :first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, 
                 :address, :money_paid, :date, :nin_number
                 # user_id and home_id should not be in the whitelist
               )
      end
    end 
  end 
end
```

I would then handle showing the users payments in a separate controller.

```
# you can also do this with `devise_scope`
resource :user, only: [] do
  resources :payments, 
    only: [:index],
    controller: :user_payments
end
```

```
class Api
  module V1
    # Displays payments for the current user
    class UserPaymentsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :authenticate_user!
      # GET /user/payments
      def index
        @payments = current_user.payments.order(created_at: :desc)
      end 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks , i have tried it but am getting this error still .     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Home with 'id'=:home_id):
which is logged to the console.   here is the route which i have passed to my payment.jsx           const url = "/api/v1/homes/:home_id/payments" with method Post

Comment: You're passing the string `":home_id"`. Of course it can't find a record. You probally meant to do something like `let url =\`/api/v1/homes/${home_id}/payments\``.

Comment: ReferenceError: home_id is not defined ii get that error in browser console.

Comment: i suspect to be missing somthing like this in my react component that is sending data to the create action <%= form_for [@home, Payment.new] do |f| %>  if it was rails

Comment: Bingo. You need to look over how you're going to pass the id of the home into your react component.